# Openstack Keystone Install Issues

Tags: openstack, keystone

When trying to create Keystone:

```
openstack domain create --description "An Example Domain" example
```

I get this return error below:

> Could not clean up: 'ClientManager' object has no attribute
> 'sdk_connection'

I am not sure what this is in reference to...

following the Doc here https://docs.openstack.org//keystone/wallaby/doc-keystone.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This means that you aren't authenticated.

```
stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$ openstack domain create --description "An Example Domain" example 
Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password
Could not clean up: 'ClientManager' object has no attribute 'sdk_connection'
```

If you are using devstack you can just source `userrc_early` inside the devstack folder.

```
stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$ source userrc_early 
stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$ openstack domain create --description "An Example Domain" example 
+-------------+----------------------------------+
| Field       | Value                            |
+-------------+----------------------------------+
| description | An Example Domain                |
| enabled     | True                             |
| id          | 1ddc2084930d492dbe39680cda5ef660 |
| name        | example                          |
| options     | {}                               |
| tags        | []                               |
+-------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm using Mircostack unfortunately

Comment: You just need to look at the microstack documentation to figure out how to authenticate.
https://microstack.run/docs/single-node

Comment: You could try `microstack.openstack <command>` , e.g. `microstack.openstack domain create`.

Comment: now I am getting http 502  Bad Gateway,   but  the  Openstack Domain is active, and I can get to Horizon Portal  -- just having authentication issues 

either way, I got it back working on a separate server,   just wish I could get back into the original ://

Comment: separate meaning the original is still broken, and I had to re-deploy on a different server

Comment: Ok, I am back in ---   essentially I just installed  wipe,  and started removing directories I had been in,  then re-did {  sudo microstack init } --auto --control  

and used a new Token/admin